# Is there a website that breaks down the 2012 presidential election results by congressional district?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election

I'm trying to find the results for the amount of votes for the Democratic party per congressional district and all I can find is the amount of votes per county, and since some congressional districts go through half a county, it isn't very helpful. I was wondering if anyone knew a great website that broke down the election results by congressional districts rather than by county.

Answer (score 1):

[Daily Kos published the presidential results by congressional district](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2012/11/19/1163009/-Daily-Kos-Elections-presidential-results-by-congressional-district-for-the-2012-2008-elections) for the 2012 and 2016 elections. It is quite comprehensive and includes their detailed calculations.

There is also an analysis done by The Cook Political Report which is accessible [here](http://cookpolitical.com/story/5606).